# Tablesorter: table.tBodies[0] is undefined (After deciding to retrieve table data via PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tablesorter

I have decided to retrieve Table data via MySQL into tablesorter, and that has caused this error to appear.

```
table.tBodies[0] is undefined
```

[You can see a demo here:](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/cropped/)

Here is what the PHP looks like if anyone is interested:

```
<?php

$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';  //the name of the database
$chandle = mysql_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die('Connection Failure to Database');
mysql_select_db($dbname, $chandle) or die ($dbname . ' Database not found. ' . $dbuser);


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bratislava');
$currentHour = date('H');
if ($currentHour < 6) {
    // logical day started yesterday
    $PHP_START_DATE = strtotime('yesterday 06:00');
}
else {
    // logical day started today
    $PHP_START_DATE = strtotime('today 06:00');
}
$PHP_END_DATE = strtotime('tomorrow 05:59:59');

$DATE_START_SELECTED = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $PHP_START_DATE);
$DATE_END_SELECTED = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $PHP_END_DATE);


$query =    
"SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    events.start_datetime,
    events.end_datetime,
    events.VENUE_LOCATION,
    events.PARTY_TYPE,
    events.IMAGE_URL,
    events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME,
    venues.BEER_PRICE,
    venues.WINE_PRICE,
    SPIRITS_PRICE, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
GROUP BY events.ID
";



$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><IMG src='" . $row['IMAGE_URL'] . "' hspace='10px'></td>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $row['VENUE_NAME'] . "</h6>" . $row['EVENT_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PARTYTYPE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ENTRANCE_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['MUSIC_STYLE_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['BEER_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['WINE_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['SPIRITS_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}

?>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hey, Can you jsfiddle it please? I might be able to help you with your link I cannot get enough information. cheers!

Comment: I will try, if I can load php filed with jquery in jsfiddle

Comment: Saweet man that will be great, will wait for your jsfiddle or I can give you a jsfiddle with simple implementation and you can see whats wrong with the set-up, cheers!

Comment: Hey Tats, I'm sorry Tats_innit but the JSFIDDLE does not work because I'm also importing a php file. I will create a very simple stripped down version on my server if that's okay.

Comment: Okies - there is a simple js fiddle for table sorter here: http://jsfiddle.net/6gjLs/4/ ;I will see in your page view source if I can spot anything, cheers!

Comment: [Hello, here is my stripped down version](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/cropped/)

Comment: Cooleos, I reckon you have initialized your table sorter somewhere else? (on your view source I cannot see table sorter initialization) like the one you can see in the jsfiddle above. Issue might be that your table sorter is not initialized properly hence this problem.

Comment: No it's initialized, see `initialConfig();` on the index page, which leads to [complete.js](http://www.nightlifebratislava.com/demos/cropped/js/complete.js). That js file only contains the tablesorter initializing function and tablesorter.

Comment: yep, cool have you notice that your thead has no closing tag **and** can you please try this instead of header and widget just want to see what will happen: $("#eventsTable").tablesorter();

Comment: Wow, the problem was in the </tr></Thead> tags... :/

Comment: Thank you so much  Tats_innit! Can you please add an answer so I can give you acceptance points please?

Comment: ha ha cool, yay! damn I lost my points I should have answered it :)

Comment: Legend man! Added the answer, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the answer rest reside in comments

Here you go this will help:

yep, cool have you notice that your **thead** has no closing tag and can you please try this instead of header and widget just want to see what will happen: $("#eventsTable").tablesorter();

or a sample here :  jsfiddle.net/6gjLs/4

cheers